# Retrieve a running exe and call a function in it

Tags: vb6, ipc, exe

I want to open a form inside my vb6 exe from shell. so first time i loaded the form using command arguments passed to the Main function in the Module. but when i try to open a form next time as the application is already running it doesnt do anything(because it checks for App.PrevInstance and Ends). 
So how to open a form from the running exe(PrevInstance). can i send a message or function name to the current running app?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the many forms of IPC to communicate with the running copy. `PostMessage()` is an option once you have the window handle, as is an ActiveX EXE, DDE, etc.